# how to change file timestamp including nanoseconds

Tags: c, file, time, stat, time.h

I am making a program to copy files from a source to a destination directory and would like to change the destination file timestamps so they match the source file timestamps.

So far I have discovered the [utime()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/utime.html) function and have manipulated the `utimbuf` struct with the times I would like to use.

However, the times do not take into account the nanoseconds.

For example:

If I want to copy "file1" and it has a timestamp of 123.213241, my copy will have 123.000000 when running my current program. I would like to include the nanoseconds .213241 etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
    struct stat buf; 
    struct utimbuf time;

    stat(filename, &buf) // get metadata of file "filename" and then store in buf

    time.actime = buf.st_atim.tv_sec; // set times in time struct
    time.modtime = buf.st_mtim.tv_sec;

    utime(filename_copy, &time); // load file copy with time struct
```

How can I include nanoseconds in my file timestamps?

Comment: _"including nanoseconds"_  are you sure your filesystem supports that? If so, create a file and duplicate its properties afterwards.

Comment: i believe so, when running the linux stat() command on both files (the copy and the original), the original has nanoseconds but the copy does not and is instead just .0000 (well for the Access and Modify times in the stat() command). Also i am trying to duplicate the properties but i dont think ```st_atim.tv_sec``` and ```st_mtim.tv_sec``` include nanoseconds for some reason.

Comment: This is not a standard feature of file system operations, so you shouldn't expect to be able to manipulate those timestamps to that level of detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to POSIX, the function you need is [`utimensat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html) (or its close relative, `futimens()`).  Both of these take a pair of `struct timespec` values in an array, which allows you to specify a time to nanoseconds.  The first element is the access time; the second is the modification time.

Not all file systems support nanosecond timestamps.  Not all systems actually support nanosecond resolution — they might round to the nearest microsecond.

Note that modern versions of the [`stat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) function return a structure with elements `st_atim`, `st_ctim`, and `st_mtim`.  These are also `struct timespec` values.  The [`<sys/stat.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) defines some backwards-compatibility macros:

> For compatibility with earlier versions of this standard, the `st_atime` macro shall be defined with the value `st_atim.tv_sec`. Similarly, `st_ctime` and `st_mtime` shall be defined as macros with the values `st_ctim.tv_sec` and `st_mtim.tv_sec`, respectively.

For Linux, see [`utimensat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utimensat).  However, the documentation for [`stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) only mentions subsecond times in the Notes section near the bottom.  Be cautious.